# Scrapy rules, callback for allowed_domains, and a different callback for denied domains

Tags: python, scrapy

In Scrapy how can I use different callback functions for allowed domains, and denied domains.

I'm using the following rules:

```
rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), deny_domains = allowed_domains), callback='parse_denied_item', follow=True),
Rule(LinkExtractor(allow_domains = allowed_domains), callback='parse_item', follow=True)]
```

Basically I want `parse_item` to be called whenever there is a request from an `allowed_domain` (or sub-domain of one of those domains). Then I want `parse_denied_item` to be called for all requests that are not whitelisted by `allowed_domains`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the best approach is *not* to use `allowed_domains` on `LinkExtractor`, and instead parse the domain out of `response.url` in your `parse_*` method and perform a different logic depending on the domain.

You can keep separate `parse_*` methods and a triaging method that, depending on the domains, calls `yield from self.parse_*(response)` (Python 3) with the corresponding `parse_*` method:

```py
rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_all', follow=True)]

def parse_all(self, response):
    # [Get domain out of response.url]
    if domain in allowed_domains:
        yield from self.parse_item(response)
    else:
        yield from self.parse_denied_item(response)
```

Comment: Could the `process_request` attribute of a `Rule` be used to capture the request before it is executed? Then filter from this point? https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Rule

Comment: Indeed, I had not thought of that. Please, add it as a response to your own question, I for one will vote that up.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Gallaecio's answer. An alternate option is to use `process_request` of `Rule`. `process_request` will capture the request before it is sent.

From my understanding (which could be wrong) Scrapy will only crawl domains listed in `self.allowed_domains` (assuming its used). However, if an offsite link is encountered on a scraped page, Scrapy will send a single request to this offsite link in some cases [1]. I'm not sure why this happens. I think this is possibly occurring because the target site is performing a 301, or 302 redirect and the crawler is automatically following that URL. Otherwise, it's probably a bug.

`process_request` can be used be used to perform processing on a request before it is executed. In my case, I wanted to log all links that aren't being crawled. So I'm verifying an allowed domain is in `request.url` before proceeding, and logging any of those that aren't.

Here is an example:

```
rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_item', process_request='process_item', follow=True)]

def process_item(self, request):
    found = False
    for url in self.allowed_domains:
        if url in request.url:
            #an allowed domain is in the request.url, proceed
            found = True

    if found == False: #otherwise log it
        self.logDeniedDomain(urlparse(request.url).netloc)

        # according to: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Rule
        # setting request to None should prevent this call from being executed (which is not the case for all)
        # middleware is used to catch these few requests
        request = None

    return request
```

[1]: If you're encountering this problem, using `process_request` in Downloader middleware appears to solve it though.

My `Downloader` middleware:

```
def process_request(self, request, spider):
    #catch any requests that should be filtered, and ignore them
    found = False
    for url in spider.allowed_domains:
        if url in request.url:
            #an allowed domain is in the request.url, proceed
            found = True

    if found == False:
        print("[ignored] "+request.url)
        raise IgnoreRequest('Offsite link, ignore')

    return None
```

Make sure you import `IgnoreRequest` as well:

```
from scrapy.exceptions import IgnoreRequest
```

and enable the Downloader middleware in `settings.py`.

To verify this, you can add some verification code in `process_item` of your crawler to ensure no requests to out of scope sites have been made.